# XNA basic highscore list

Tags: xna, storage, xna-4.0

I'm looking to implement a basic highscore list of top ten scores. It would just store locally on xbox/pc and not need any networking/global sync. I tried updating the link below to xna4 but received serializing errors on both formats and also issues with pulling the score data into a nice screen format - any ideas or alternative ways?
http://xnaessentials.com/tutorials/highscores.aspx/tutorials/highscores.aspx

Also what would be the suggested way to enter in the players name using gamepad? (without using the profile name)

Thanks
Paul.

Comment: Did you get an error when trying to save a high score list or load one?  Also, can you give more details about the error?  You are going to want to use XML serialization and the tutorial seems right to me.

Comment: I updated the - Path.Combine line with TitleLocation and just hard coded the path "/content/hi.lst" - this works ok on PC. That works and load and saves most of the time but on occasion I receive an error "There is an error in xml document(52, 17)" - which is the position at the very end of the file where and extra > symbol is added - it appears the file is either updating/overwritting but slightly out of place to the original - I've tried updating to File.Write and also Create instead of OpenorCreate but this doesn't change the error. 

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the `HighScoreData` definition only contains a reference to the array elements, not the elements themselves, since they are intitialized in its constructor. The XmlSerializer has no idea what `count` is nor can it call a parametered constructor. Since HighScoreData is a `struct`, you cannot define a parameterless constructor (and the one taking place "behind the scenes" is not creating your array elements).

The solution (that changes as little of that code as possible) is to change `HighScoreData` into a `class` and create a parameterless constructor. To do the latter, you will have to decide in advance the size of the arrays. So:

```
public class HighScoreData
{
    public string[] PlayerName;
    public int[] Score;
    public int[] Level;

    public const int MaxScores = 100;

    public HighScoreData()
    {
        PlayerName = new string[MaxScores];
        Score = new int[MaxScores];
        Level = new int[MaxScores];
    }
}
```